# How to visualize 'suicides_no' w.r.t 'gdp_per_capita ($)' for a given country over the years, in the following data frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, data-visualization, seaborn

The DataFrame can be viewed here: [Global Suicide Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/russellyates88/suicide-rates-overview-1985-to-2016)

I have made a pivot table with country and year as indices using the following code:

```
df1 = pd.pivot_table(df, index = ['country', 'year'],
                     values=['suicides_no','gdp_per_capita ($)', 'population', 'suicides/100k pop'],
                     aggfunc = {"suicides_no" : np.sum
                               ,"gdp_per_capita ($)" : np.mean
                               ,"population" : np.mean
                               ,"suicides/100k pop" : np.mean})
```

Output:
[image]

Now for my project, i want to visualize how does the suicides_no vary with the gdp_per_capita for a country over the years. But I am unable to plot it. Can somebody please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

First lets convert indexes to columns using `df1.reset_index(inplace=True)`

Now, you can draw this in a scatter plot where the main features are - Year (preferably on x-axis) and suicides_no (on y-axis). The gdp_per_capita will go as size of the dots.

In this case you have two options:

1. Draw different plots for each country. (gdp will be shown as hue)

`sns.catplot(x='year', y='suicides_no', row='country', hue='gdp_per_capita ($)', data=df1)`

2. Draw everything in a single plot. Scatter plot with GDP as dot size, and Country as Color (hue)

`sns.scatterplot(x='year', y='suicides_no', hue='country', size='gdp_per_capita ($)', data=df1)`